# Basic search engine not working

Tags: php

Hello i managed to make a simple search engine its basic so i started working on that..
But i get Access Forbidden and dont know why can someone help me?
with a form i give the $find the word i search and it should search for it..
thx for your time!`

```
    <?php

    if ($searching =="yes")  
    {   
    echo "Results";

    if ($find == "")   
    {   
    echo "You forgot to enter a search term";  
     exit;   
    }   
    mysql_connect("localhost","Anton","zouzou13") or die(mysql_error());  mysql_select_db("Ptyxiakh") or  die(mysql_error());
    $find = strtoupper($find);

    $find = strip_tags($find);

    $find = trim ($find);

    $data =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE keywords LIKE'%$find%'");  
     while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))   
    {   
    echo $result['document_name'];   
    echo " ";
    echo $result['first_paragraph'];
    echo "<br>";     
    } 
     $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data);
    if ($anymatches == 0)   
    {   
    echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>";   }
     echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find;   }  ?>

ok i made it simpler to see if it works like this:

    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    mysql_connect("localhost","Anton","zouzou13") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("Ptyxiakh") or die(mysql_error()); 


     //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE keywords LIKE 'helmets'");

      while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))   
    {   
    echo $result['document_name'];   
    echo " ";
    echo $result['first_paragraph'];
    echo "<br>";     
    }

     $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
     if ($anymatches == 0) 
     { 
     echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
     }
    ?> 
But i get the "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; so i cant connect to database?its just wont work :(



With PDO it should be like this??:

<?php
 //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
 if ($searching =="yes") 
 { 
 echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

 //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
 if ($find == "") 
 { 
 echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
 exit; 
 } 
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ptyxiakh', 'Anton', 'zouzou13');
 // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
//mysql_connect("localhost","Anton","zouzou13") or die(mysql_error()); 
//mysql_select_db("Ptyxiakh") or die(mysql_error()); 

 // We preform a bit of filtering 
 $find = strtoupper($find); 
 $find = strip_tags($find); 
 $find = trim ($find); 

 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 //$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE keywords LIKE'%$find%'"); 
 $data= $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE keywords LIKE'%$find%'");

 //And we display the results 
 while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
 { 
 echo htmlentities($row['document_name']); 
 echo " "; 
 echo htmlentities($row['first_paragraph']);
 echo "<br>";   
 } 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 

 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
 } 
?>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Formatting! It makes or breaks questions.

Comment: ok fixed it now! i never found a good PDO example can you give me a guide or something?

Comment: [Google is your friend.](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=getting+started+with+php+pdo)

Comment: mysql_query() returns a value which is a resource upon success and FALSE on failure.  You might want to test this value before you use it in mysql_fetch_array().  You might also want to add error_reporting(E_ALL) to the top of the script to be sure your script does not rely on an undefined variable (hint: It does!)

Comment: what you mean error_reporting can you write me code for that? thx for quick answer!

Comment: Sure... Add this statement to the top of the script: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: i dont know why but it worked i had a ?=$PHP_SELF? at the form because i was sending the data at the same page but when i made 2 different files it worked! now i just need to make it look right!

Answer (score 0):

i made it work its pretty basic and i guess it has deprecated thingys but il upload for ppl that search for things...
just make a simple form and then make a php file

```
    <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
 echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 
 $find =$_POST["find"];
 //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
 if ($find == "") 
 { 
 echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
 exit; 
 } 
 // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost","Anton","zouzou13") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("Ptyxiakh") or die(mysql_error()); 

 // We preform a bit of filtering 
 $find = strtoupper($find); 
 $find = strip_tags($find); 
 $find = trim ($find); 

 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE keywords LIKE'%$find%'"); 

 //And we display the results 
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))   
    {
    echo '<p> <strong>',$result['document_name'], '</strong> <br> ', $result['first_paragraph'],'... <br> </p>';
    }

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 

 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 

?>
```

This worked for me :) thx!